# Не работает программа, которая "переворачивает" числа

Tags: pascal

Написал программу, которая "переворачивает" число. Допустим берём `654`- получаем `456`. Но она работает по непонятной причине только с 4-х значными числами(но есть исключения, например `10001` работает, `10008` нет). На 5 и более значные числа выдаёт какие-то другие числа, иногда даже отрицательные.
Вот код:

```
function IntToStr(i:integer): string;
var
   s: string;
begin
   Str(i, s);
   IntToStr:=s;
end;

function StrToInt(s:string):integer;
var
   i: integer;
begin
  Val(s, i);
  StrToInt:=i;
end;

function rN(a:integer):integer;
 var
    n, m:string;
    i:integer;
 begin
    n:=IntToStr(a);
    m:='';
    for i:=0 to length(n) - 1 do
       m:=m + n[length(n) - i];
    rN:=StrToInt(m);
  end;

var
   b: integer;
begin
   readln(b);
   writeln(rN(b));
end.
```

Где у меня ошибка?

Comment: Почитайте справку по форматированию. Количество (а иногда и качество) специалистов, которых заинтересует вопрос, прямо пропорционально качеству форматирования.

Comment: `for i:=0 to length(n) - 1 do`? Если мне не изменяет память, строки в Паскале индексируются с 1, а не с 0? Или это уже не так?

Comment: нормально: `n[length(n) - i]`

Comment: `for i := length(n) downto 1 do m := m + n[i];`

Comment: На сколько я помню Pascal, `integer` — это двухбайтовое знаковое целое, диапазон значений -32768–32767. Поместить туда 80001 у Вас вряд ли получиться.

Comment: "integer — это двухбайтовое знаковое целое" - только в Delphi 1

Comment: http://www.pascal.helpov.net/index/numerical_data_types_pascal_programming

Comment: Пардон, был неправ

Comment: Кто-нибудь хочет написать полноценный ответ?

Comment: Хотелось бы реализовать это для типа longint. С функциями поможете? А так впринципе спасибо, понял про типы.

Comment: @Alexajax: Ну, поменяйте `int` на `longint`, посмотрите чтобы компилировалось (может, пару других функций нужно будет вызывать).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
function rN(a: Integer): Integer;
var
  n, m: string;
  i: Integer;
begin
  n := IntToStr(a);
  m:='';
  for i := Length(n) downto 1 do
     m := m + n[i];
  rN := StrToInt(m);
end;
```

Символы в строке **всегда** нумеруются с единицы. Если упрощенно, то строку можно представить как `array [1..n] of Char;`

Comment: Добавьте в чем у автора была ошибка - ему будет полезно.

Comment: с индексацией у автора все в порядке

Answer (score 1):

Программа у Вас вполне рабочая. Единственная проблема — это диапазон значений типа `integer`. Простой заменой `integer` на `longint` Вы можете добиться того, что программа будет работать для девятизначных чисел. Однако, Вашу программу можно упростить, если убрать переход к строкам. Целочисленных операций вполне достаточно, для решения задачи.

```
function rN(a:longint):longint;
    var
        i:longint;
    begin
        i:=0;
        while a > 0 do begin
            i:=i * 10 + a mod 10;
            a:=a div 10;
        end;
        rN:=i;
    end;

var
   b: longint;
begin
   readln(b);
   writeln(rN(b));
end.
```

[Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/rKhkuE)

Comment: Спасибо, знал о таком способе, просто хотелось именно работы со строками.

Answer (score 1):

Кажется, как-то так:

```
var
  s: string,
  i: integer;
begin
  readln(s);
  for i:=length(s) downto 1 do write(s[i]);
  writeln();
end.
```

Зачем мудрить-то?

---

Вариант выше не учитывал лидирующие нули в обоих числах. Правильно так:

https://ideone.com/FgXRTU

```
program ideone;
var
  s: string;
  i, l, r: integer;
begin
  readln(s);

  r:=length(s);
  while((r>1) and (s[r]='0')) do r:=r-1;

  l:=1;
  while((l<r) and (s[l]='0')) do l:=l+1;

  for i:=r downto l do write(s[i]);
  writeln();
end.
```